# Migrating to MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathoverflow, migration

Should not Math.SE implement a close option with migration to MathOverflow?

Would I be encouraged to ask a question there, that is at the appropriate level, despite having asked it here, where it is not getting any attention? Would it be a bad idea?

Comment: Let us wait and see a bit. There are two issues involved: (a) in principle Math.SE does _not_ consider research level questions off-topic, even though MathOverflow will often be a better place to ask and (b) those involved in the integration process seem to believe that MO mods have veto power over whether a migration path to MO is opened (see Francois Dorais' comment buried halfway down [this discussion](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/5/mathoverflow-20/)).

Comment: And as user85506 mentioned below, you can always ask a moderator to migrate a post to MO (subject to the usual [rules](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6818/1543)). And even if we ignore the two issues I raised above, SE generally prefers to evaluate the need for opening a migration path after gathering some data on its necessity. Since MO has only be in the SE network for 2 weeks and there have been only 7 questions passed over so far, it is a bit too early to say something about it.

Comment: ... incidentally, with 626 rep, you can't vote to close anyway. Why so interested? `:-)`

Comment: @WillieWong Flags to close are almost equivalent to votes to close these days, with almost the same dialog. They are not even shown in moderator-only queue anymore, going straight into Close Review. However, flags to close cannot have a custom off-topic reason. One can only choose from  existing off-topic reasons, including open migration paths.

Comment: @user85506 But why would you ever want to close here a question that would be appropriate for MO?

Comment: @user85506: if the migration path is _not_ open to the 3Ks, what good will it do to use a custom close reason?  Wouldn't it be *much better* to just flag for moderator attention using the free-form field?

Comment: @WillieWong (& Michael): I was replying to "with 626 rep, you can't vote to close anyway. Why so interested?". My reply was that the OP could be naturally interested in having an open migration path, because it would allow him to exercise the flag-to-close-and-migrate option. Not saying that this is something that *should* be done.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, as MO is part of the StackExchange network, and the former is at least as much related to Math.SE as is CrossValidated.SE or Physics.SE, Math.SE should implement migration to MO in the flagging menu.

Answer (score 12):

> ...  having asked it here, where it is not getting any attention?

In such a situation (MO-level post not getting any action at MSE), you, the question owner, can request migration to MO by flagging your post for moderator's attention.

The above situation is largely unrelated to the question of whether there should be an established migration path to MO. Such a path  would allow *other* users to migrate your post there, whether you want it or not.  My opinion is that there is no need to open   migration path to MO.