# Migration from M.SE to M.O by OP

Tags: discussion, migration, mathoverflow

Can one migrate own question  from *math.stackexchange.com* to *mathoverflow.net* or Conversely? Could this be a help for moderators?

Comment: There are flags on couple of questions requesting such a migration. Personally I have been reluctant to act on them, and for real life reasons I have not had time to discuss this with other moderators. At least not adequately. Ok, so the at least somewhat difficult question has not received an answer here, but that does not necessarily mean that the quesion is at research level. May be the difficulties are technical so that nobody simply bothered to take a serious look at it? No reason to think that the reception at MO would be any different.

Comment: And I am admittedly reluctant to initiate a migration as that somehow attaches to it my evaluation of it being on-topic for MO. There are relatively few questions, where I think I am qualified to decide that they are at research level.

Comment: You can find several older discussions on both [migration](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathoverflow+migration) and [cross-posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathoverflow+cross-posting) questions to MO.

Comment: Personally, I only have two questions on MO. One of them was migrated. In the other case I have posted new version on MO. (Since I felt it needed some rewriting because of a differences between the two sites.) [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369?m=14887143#14887143) you can find some advice I was given when I discussed possibility of migration of my question with a more experienced MO user.

Comment: Your question has been down-voted and criticized for the same reasons why you require an answer to the question. This isn't entirely fair, but it is with good reason that these sites are kept well-organized by some diligent people. Try not to take it personally and follow the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking whether the OP can migrate question by themselves or whether some intervention by the moderators is needed.

The question cannot be migrated by the OP.

If you want to migrate your post to MO, you should flag the question for moderators attention and explain in the flag that you want to migrate the question. (Maybe you could also explain the reasons why you want to migrate the question.)

Don't forget that the questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.

(A question can also be migrated to another site without moderator intervention, if enough users vote to close it as off-topic and choose to option to migrate. But MathOverflow is [not among the migration paths on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/migrating-to-mathoverflow).)

For more details about how migration works see
[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

---

If you decide to repost your question on MO rather than migrate, it is recommended, that you clearly state in both posts that the same question is asked on the other site and link to the other post, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088). Both cross-posting and migration have some advantages and disadvantages, see this discussion: [Cross posting, or flag for migration?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration)